# Динамическая подгрузка записей

Tags: jquery

Уже сломал себе мозг... 
Проблема такая. Мне нужно подгрузить записи если был скролинг до подвала. 
Уже что только не делал, но проблема в том что запрос на получение доп. блоков отправляется несколько раз. и дубликаты блоков грузятся по 5-6 раз. 
Вот скрипт:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){    
        var launch = 0;
        var foot =  $('footer').position().top - $('footer').height();
        if($(".action_block:last").attr('data-npage') >= {{$max_page}}) {
            var launch = 1;
        }
        if($(this).scrollTop()>= foot && launch == 0){
                launch = 1;
                $('#loader-icon').show();               
                var pagenum = parseInt($(".action_block:last").attr('data-npage')) + 1;
                var url = window.location.href;                 
                $.ajax({
                    url: url+'?page='+pagenum,                   
                    type: "GET",
                    beforeSend: function(){
                        $('#loader-icon').show();
                    },
                    complete: function(){
                        $('#loader-icon').hide();
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                        $("#actions_block").append(data);
                        // var launch = 0;
                    },
                    error: function(){}             
                    });
        }       
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не посылайте новых запросов во время выполнения уже посланного.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($("#actions_block").data("loading") == "loading") // !!!
    return;

  var launch = 0;
  var foot = $('footer').position().top - $('footer').height();
  if ($(".action_block:last").attr('data-npage') >= {
      {
        $max_page
      }
    }) {
    var launch = 1;
  }
  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= foot && launch == 0) {
    launch = 1;
    $('#loader-icon').show();
    var pagenum = parseInt($(".action_block:last").attr('data-npage')) + 1;
    var url = window.location.href;
    $("#actions_block").data("loading", "loading"); // !!!
    $.ajax({
      url: url + '?page=' + pagenum,
      type: "GET",
      beforeSend: function() {
        $('#loader-icon').show();
      },
      complete: function() {
        $('#loader-icon').hide();
        $("#actions_block").data("loading", ""); // !!!
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $("#actions_block").append(data);
        // var launch = 0;
      },
      error: function() {}
    });
  }
})
```